# Jquery ajax timeout best practice value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Did a search on google to find out if there are any recommended best practice on min/max timeout setting for Jquery Ajax call.

Scenario:

*ASP.NET MVC Web application that uses third party WCF Relay service. Once data is retrieved, this web application has it's own business rules, which once gets processed it gets exposed by controller/action.*

Could someone please share below?

1. What's the recommended timeout e.g. 5 second, 10 second, 1 minute etc.?
2. What's the consequence if we specify a greater value for timeout? Will there be a blocking threads.
3. Finally any issue if we don't specify the timeout i.e. use of box ?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) depends on the amount of data being transferred and the speed of processing. Generally 15 seconds is enough. 2) So long as it's async it won't block anything, it may just use more server resources. 3) timeout defaults to 60 seconds i believe, although it may be dependent on the browser's network connection timeout.

Comment: 1. whatever floats your boat, usually it's 30 seconds. 2. Ajax will never block the thread, even if you set a longer timeout. 3. no issues, if you don't set it, jQuery at least will set it to 30 seconds for you.

Comment: Basically our web application relies on external web service and we have some business rules to process as well

Answer (score 1):

A standard value is ten seconds, though as others have mentioned above binary streams can take longer. Perhaps wrap your XHR in a constructor that takes an

```
this.timeout = timeout || 10000
```

arg. That way you're not rewriting boilerplate, but can bump it up for routes expected to take longer.